# Simple rectangle method algorithm problem

Tags: c, algorithm, integral

I've been asked to write a rectangle method algorithm to calculate estimated area of function, however, my lecturer sent my code back and asked me to correct it, because ending condition is wrong?

```
double prostokaty(double( *f)(double))
{
    double krok, p, suma = 0;
    krok = (c_do - c_od) / lp;
    for (p = c_od + krok; p < c_do; p += krok) {
        suma += (*f)(p);
    }
    return suma * krok;      
}
```

I've spent almost two hours, figuring out whats wrong and I failed.

Comment: Show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I think you need to do p <= c_do.

Comment: `(*f)(p)` can be written as `f(p)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use the middle `c_od + krok/2` of the rectangle rather than the right edge `c_od + krok`.

```
double prostokaty(double( *f)(double)) {
  double p, suma = 0;
  double krok = (c_do - c_od) / lp;
  // for (p = c_od + krok; p < c_do; p += krok) {
  for (p = c_od + krok/2; p < c_do; p += krok) {
    suma += (*f)(p);
  }
  return suma * krok;      
}
```

If `lp` is an integer type, better to avoid accumulated increment errors.

```
  double suma = 0;
  double krok = (c_do - c_od) / lp;
  for (int i = 0; i < lp; i++) {
    double p = c_od + (i + 0.5)*krok;
    suma += f(p);
  }
  return suma * krok;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I will stick to the first version, since lp is defined as double